# Cannot create new activity android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have a problem with android studio. I'm developing a project where I have so many activities. But now, I've updated Android Studio to version 3.4 (April 2019) and I can't create a new activity.
The ide doesn't show any error message, I press New> Empty Activity and I write the name of the activity and press 'Finish' but nothing happens in the layout.
Does anybody know what kind of error it is?
Thanks.

[image: New Activity]

[image: New>Activity]

[image: No activity created in layoud]

Comment: @Shantnav Please don't edit the question to address the OP. When you have sufficient rep, you will be able to leave comments on the question for things like that.

Comment: There are several compiler errors thrown in the project. Clear those compiler errors and see if it's working again..

Comment: Was the build successful?

Comment: I have removed the lines which was causing the build error and I tried to create again the new activity but it doesn't work

Answer (score 10):

Delete caches folder from `C:\Users\user Name\.AndroidStudio4.0\system`
worked for me.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for Android Studio 4.0.1

Answer (score 4):

I had a same issue with my android studio 4.0. just go to this directory  **C:\Users\user Name.AndroidStudio4.0\system** And delete caches and then try to create new activity. It will work.

Answer (score 3):

Doing the following might help:-

#### Clear Cache

First go to `Build` -> `Clean Project`.  (Clears your Build Folders)

If the above doesn't works, then do this:

`File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart` and again open `Android Studio`

Even if that doesn't works, then remove your `.gradle` directory from the root of your project. It contains some Gradle cache files.

Answer (score 2):

i had to face the same error when i was creating a new activity ,. we had to do what, we check the AndroidManifest.xml file and if there is an error then resolve it, after that you can able to create an new activity...try this at ones

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem too.
For me, it works by upgrading android studio 4.1.1.[image]

Answer (score 1):

open up the build at the bottom see if you get a hint.check if the directory path isn't too long or starts with smaller case(although doesn't affect but throws a suggestion)

Comment: Hi how are you, mm no I don't have a hint.check in the build, Is there a limit for the quantity of activities? I have 31 at the moment

Comment: no there's no such thing. you can have 'n' number of activities. Check if you have enableMultiDex true in gradle. and see if that solves the problem

Comment: I think that the error is because i don't have the kotlin plugin upgraded. I'm going to check that thank you 'Learner Ishere'

Comment: why kotlin??? your coding in java. i suggested the use multi dex because you have more activity.

Comment: Hi Learner, Android studio has launched a new version and now I can create the new Activities.. problem resolved ! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Umm i think you should try another method to make activity that is navigation graph.
In navigation graph it is very easy to make new activity and manage them and it is a new features in android studio making your work fast.

To create navigation graph go to Project>res>Right click>New>Android Resource file>
And then give any name and set Resource type to navigation.

It is very exiting and easy.
See this website if you are interested:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your android studio, while uninstalling the android studio click on the clear all cache option with it... with that i think it should work when you install it once more. It worked for me

Comment: You dont have to reinstall android studio to clear cache. There is an option to invalidate all  cache and restart

Comment: yeah i tried that but it didn't work for me. so when i did a reinstall it worked.