# Can't create an activity in Android Studio 4.0, no files created, no error

Tags: android, android-studio

Can't create a new activity in my project. I see some similar questions floating around without useful answer: [Cannot create new activity android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104706/cannot-create-new-activity-android-studio)
here author upgraded Studio and the problem went away. But then was 3.x version and there is no upgrade for 4.0.

In my own case, it does not work only in my work project. If I create a new project then I can create an activity there, but not inside my work project. I click right button, new, choose empty activity (or any other activity), fill the dialog, click finish and nothing. No error, no new files, nothing.

Things already tried:

1. Invalidated cache, did not help.
2. Synced with gradle files, did not help.
3. Checked out my code as new, without .idea directory. Did not help.
4. Installed Android Studio Beta 4.1, did not help. It behaves the same way as stable studio.

Comment: Having the same problem right now. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

to creating default activity make sure that use legacy android.support libraries checkbox is checked

[image]